Why doesn't it require breaking a bond for a valence electron to fill a neighboring hole?
I am watching a lecture series on semiconductor physics on YouTube and I am at a point where the professor is explaining the concept of a hole and how bounded electrons (valence electrons of an atom covalently bonded to valence electrons of other silicon atoms) contribute to current (this part of the lecture starts at timestamp 23:18 in the lecture video linked below). The professor in this part of the lecture states the following:
"For a bonded electron to jump into a vacancy (hole) requires negligible energy, it takes a lot of energy for it to become free but it doesn't take much energy for a bounded electron to jump into a neighboring vacancy." (Quote from timestamp 30:34 in the lecture video linked below)
My question is doesn't a bonded valence electron need to break free from it's bond before it hops into a neighboring hole? The professor in this quote makes it seem like a bond doesn't need to broken and that it requires less energy to move a bonded electron into a neighboring hole.
Lecture Video Link:
https://youtu.be/-Lm__i7a-lM?si=zu21ODVoNNcbF6zq&t=1834

From that perspective, how to electrons move? Electronic structure in crystals is described by solid state band structure, and holes act just like electrons, just in the valence band.

@JonCuster But my question is doesn't the bounded electron need to break it's bond to move into the hole in the valence band?

No, neither electrons in the conduction band nor holes in the valence band are bound to individual atoms.

@JonCuster I'm confused isn't the semiconductor lattice formed by bonded valence electrons?

Well, yes, but not the way you think. They are delocalized, not attached to a given atom.

That professor is an electrical engineering professor and not a physics professor. He says the bond energy is 1.1 eV. That's the band gap in silicon. It is not a bond energy. Besides that, the idea of bonds as little sticks between atoms that you break is archaic.
